# How to properly set labels in contourf subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, contourf

I am trying to get rid of these purple points on the picture below. Here is my code:

```
p_values = [0., 0.05, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 5, 10, np.inf]
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-3, 3, num = 101),
                     np.linspace(-3, 3, num = 101))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols = (len(p_values) + 1) // 2,
                         nrows = 2, figsize = (16, 7))

for p, ax in zip(p_values, axes.flat):
    ### BEGIN Solution (do not delete this comment)
    z = np.linalg.norm([xx, yy], ord = p, axis = 0) 
    ax.contourf(yy, xx, z, 25, cmap = 'coolwarm')
    ax.contour(yy, xx, z, [1], colors = 'fuchsia', linewidths = 3)
    ax.set_title(f'p = {p}')
    ax.legend([f'$x: |x|_{{{p}}} = 1$']);
    ### END Solution (do not delete this comment)
plt.show()
```

Which parameters should be specified in ax.legend() in order to plot the graph clear.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. It just outputs this warning 'No handles with labels found to put in legend.' and doesn't show any legends. Btw, thank you for comment.

Comment: Now it works perfect, thank you! Please, can you post this comment as an answer in order to resolve the question.

Comment: No, everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could create the legend using an explicit handle.  In this case the fuchsia colored line is stored as the last element of `ax.collections`. Creating the legend with only labels, when there were no "handles with labels" set, could be the cause of the weird purple dots.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

p_values = [0., 0.05, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 5, 10, np.inf]
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-3, 3, num=101),
                     np.linspace(-3, 3, num=101))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=(len(p_values) + 1) // 2,
                         nrows=2, figsize=(16, 7))
cmap = plt.get_cmap('magma').copy()
cmap.set_extremes(over='green', under='black', bad='turquoise')
for p, ax in zip(p_values, axes.flat):
    ### BEGIN Solution (do not delete this comment)
    z = np.linalg.norm([xx, yy], ord=p, axis=0)
    cnt = ax.contourf(yy, xx, z, 25, cmap='coolwarm')
    ax.contour(yy, xx, z, [1], colors='fuchsia', linewidths=3)
    ax.set_title(f'p = {p}')
    ax.legend(handles=[ax.collections[-1]], labels=[f'$x: |x|_{{{p}}} = 1$'])
    plt.colorbar(cnt, ax=ax)
    ### END Solution (do not delete this comment)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: showing contour line in legend]